# Сравнить 2 List<String> поэлементно

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Суть задачи в следующем. Есть 2 `List<String>`, содержащие одинаковое количество элементов. Нужно написать написать метод, который вернет `true` только в том случае, если каждый `!list1.get(i).equal(list2.get(i))`

Я сделал это следующим образом

```
boolean flag = true;
for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
     if (list1.get(i).equals(list2.get(i))) {
        flag = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Но, возможно, это можно как-то сделать более элегатно через Stream.API.

Заранее спасибо

Comment: `return false` и нафиг флаг.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

как-то так можно сравнить

```
IntStream.range(0, list1.size()).allMatch(i -> list1.get(i).equals(list2.get(i)))
```

и весь код

```
package test;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList();
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList();

    list1.add("one");
    list1.add("two");
    list1.add("three");

    list2.add("one");
    list2.add("two");
    list2.add("three");

    System.out.println(compareLists(list1, list2));

    list1.add("foure");
    list2.add("five");

    System.out.println(compareLists(list1, list2));
  }

  public static boolean compareLists(List<String> list1, List<String> list2) {

    return IntStream.range(0, list1.size()).allMatch(i -> list1.get(i).equals(list2.get(i)));
  }
}
```

**PS.** Надеюсь конфликт исчерпан